# AS3 Nullify Object through Reference

Tags: actionscript-3

I have seem people asking this question, and getting an answer saying that this is impossible in AS3.

So I have a function called destroymc:

```
function destroymc(mcname:MovieClip):void{
    mcname = null
}
```

This doesnot destroy the movieclip I want to destroy. Because it is passed by reference.

Is there really no way to make this work?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, as far as I know, to 'destroy' a MovieClip in AS3.0, you need to get rid of all references to it, and you need to remove it from the parent. Then the GC can collect it.

If you have an array of MovieClips, then something like this could work.

```
var mcs:Array;
// populate array

// to destroy the first one
mcs[0].parent.removeChild(mcs[0]); // remove the first element from its parent
mcs.shift(); // remove the first element in the array
```

And so if you want in in a function, you could pass the array to it

```
function destroymc(mcs:Array){
    mcs[0].parent.removeChild(mcs[0]);
    mcs.shift();
}
```

I'm using an array here because you need to use functions like this with dynamically generated MovieClips and entity managers and stuff. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I already know how to remove it from the display list, but the problem is it's hard to get rid of all references. I know you can set a object to null, but not after you pass is by reference to a function. This is the main thing here I don't know..

Comment: I see. Can't help you with that, just organise your code to not have redundant references. Instead of passing references to functions dealing with MovieClips, have a central array or arrays for different kinds and pass indexes or id's to the functions which then act on the array.

Comment: Also, when you target objects with event listeners, use 'weak' references.

Comment: Also, in order to let GC collect it, the movieclip itself has to be set to null right?

Comment: It doesn't have to be null, if you no longer have any references it loses scope and is ready to be garbage collected. Careful if you plan on using weak reference listeners as they can be unpredictable and cause more harm than good.

Comment: I see, so if I past the object into a function, does this count as a reference? will the object be collected if the function contains a reference?

Comment: It is passed by reference, but the reference is temporary to the function scope, it won't exist after the function is executed.